# Question on orthogonal complement of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have proven this property:
Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space V. Then $W^\perp_1 +W^\perp_2=(W_1\cap W_2)^\perp$

So I was wondering is this result also works on vector spaces with infinite dimension. I was trying to come up with a counter-example but I got stuck quickly.

Comment: What does your argument look like? Isn't it obvious that $(W_1 \cap W_2)^\perp \subseteq W_1^\perp + W_2^\perp$? Then the other direction needs to be shown. So let $a+b\in W_1^\perp + W_2^\perp$...

Comment: @nayrb No, $W_1^\perp + W_2^\perp \subseteq (W_1\cap W_2)^\perp$ is the obvious one. The inclusion $(W_1 \cap W_2)^\perp \subseteq W_1^\perp + W_2^\perp$ isn't obvious.

Comment: @Cath, what structure have you to define $W^\perp$, and how do you define it? Do you know anything about topological concepts yet?

Comment: @DanielFischer Whoops, got my subset orderings mixed up. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: To prove that $W^\perp_1 +W^\perp_2 \subseteq (W_1+W_2)^\perp$  I didn't use the dimension, I used it to prove the other side by constructing and orthogonal basis of V.

Comment: To define $W^\perp$ I use the internal product and $W^\perp$ is the subspace of all the vectors that are ortogonal with all the vectors of $W$.

Comment: I don't really know much about topological concepts.

Comment: Pity, the last. However. The inner product gives you a norm on the space, $\lVert v\rVert = \sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$, and that gives you a distance between two vectors, $d(v,w) = \lVert v - w\rVert$. And that induces a topology on the space. Now, one thing that is different in the infinite-dimensional case is that different subspaces can have the same "orthogonal complement" (it's not necessarily a complement in the algebraic sense). The fact of the matter is that for all $v$, the linear form $w \mapsto \langle v,w\rangle$ is continuous, and that means a) $W^\perp$ is a _closed_ subspace,

Comment: and b) every subspace has the same "orthogonal complement" as its closure, $\overline{W}^\perp = W^\perp$. (A subspace $W$ being closed means it contains all limits of convergent sequences whose terms belong to $W$.) Furthermore, if the space is complete, one has $W^{\perp\perp} = \overline{W}$, the orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement of a subspace is the closure of the subspace. Now, the fact of the matter is that we do not always have $W_1^\perp + W_2^\perp = (W_1\cap W_2)^\perp$. For example, one can have two subspaces with trivial intersection, which are both dense in the

Comment: space, and that means you have $W_1^\perp = W_2^\perp = \{0\}$, but $(W_1\cap W_2)^\perp = \{0\}^\perp = V$. If $V$ is complete, you have the equality for closed subspaces, but not in general. If $V$ is not complete, I think you don't even have equality for all closed subspaces. I'm sure you don't understand all that yet, but at least now you know why you didn't manage to show equality.

Comment: Thank you so much! The thing I don't really understand is the fact that if the space is complete we have that the orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement of a subspace is the closure of the subspace

Comment: @Daniel, if it takes three comments, it's an answer. Let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.